# How to change the text of a TextView in a listView using a dialog box

Tags: java, android, listview, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am working on a `listView` and I want to change the second text i.e. `version_number` by a dialog box. So when the user clicks on the list item a dialog box appears which has `EditText` field and when he enters 'yes'(positive value) the value of the text changes to the text entered by user.

Here's my code

**HealthActivity.java**

```
public class HealthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_health);

    final ArrayList<List> disease = new ArrayList<List>();

    disease.add(new List("BP", "120/80", R.drawable.blood_pressure));
    disease.add(new List("Sugar Level(before meal)", "90", R.drawable.sugar));
    disease.add(new List("Sugar Level(after meal)", "130", R.drawable.sugar1));
    disease.add(new List("Pulse Rate", "70", R.drawable.heart_rate));
    disease.add(new List("Heart Rate", "70", R.drawable.heart_rate));


    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, disease);

    // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
    // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
    // activity_numbers.xml layout file.
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_flavor);

    // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link ArrayAdapter} we created above, so that the
    // {@link ListView} will display list items for each word in the list of words.
    // Do this by calling the setAdapter method on the {@link ListView} object and pass in
    // 1 argument, which is the {@link ArrayAdapter} with the variable name itemsAdapter.
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
}
```

**List.java**

```
public class List {

private String mDiseaseName;
private String mPersonStatus;
private int mImageResourceId;

public List(String diseaseName,String personStatus,int imageResourceId){
    mDiseaseName=diseaseName;
    mPersonStatus=personStatus;
    mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;

}

public String getDiseaseName(){
    return mDiseaseName;
}

public String getPersonStatus(){
    return mPersonStatus;
}

public int getImageResourceId() {
    return mImageResourceId;
}

}
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List> {

private static final String LOG_TAG =ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * This is our own custom constructor (it doesn't mirror a superclass constructor).
 * The context is used to inflate the layout file, and the list is the data we want
 * to populate into the lists.
 *
 * @param context        The current context. Used to inflate the layout file.
 * @param androidFlavors A List of AndroidFlavor objects to display in a list
 */
public ListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<List> androidFlavors) {
    // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
    // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
    // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
    // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
    super(context, 0, androidFlavors);
}

/**
 * Provides a view for an AdapterView (ListView, GridView, etc.)
 *
 * @param position The position in the list of data that should be displayed in the
 *                 list item view.
 * @param convertView The recycled view to populate.
 * @param parent The parent ViewGroup that is used for inflation.
 * @return The View for the position in the AdapterView.
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
    List currentAndroidFlavor = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.version_name);
    // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
    // set this text on the name TextView
    nameTextView.setText(currentAndroidFlavor.getDiseaseName());

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
    TextView numberTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.version_number);
    // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
    // set this text on the number TextView
    numberTextView.setText(currentAndroidFlavor.getPersonStatus());

    ImageView iconView=(ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    iconView.setImageResource(currentAndroidFlavor.getImageResourceId());

    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an 
ImageView)
    // so that it can be shown in the ListView
    return listItemView;
}

}
```

**activity_health.xml**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview_flavor"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

/>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/version_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/version_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, long id) {
        //show your dialog and do this code in the 'yes' callback
        List data= disease.get(position);
        data.setPersonStatus("your edit text data");
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    });
```